# Nextcloud customiztion

Tags: webdav, owncloud, nextcloud

I would like to provide Nextcloud access from Internet for my Organization's users. But I would like to do some customization. Can any one guide me that those customization are possible or not. These customization are given below.

1. I would like configure Nextcloud Server such that after successful login of the User, the user's data will be fetched from the database to the Proxy server(e.g. IMAP client) and that data will be visible to the successful user from webInterface which has been copied on proxy server.
   NextCloud<-->Proxy Server<-->Database
2. Is it possible to provide File level security like Extended ACLs of files on linux in Nextcloud.

Comment: Sorry, but it is impossible to answer to those two questions, you will have to explain better what you actually mean... 1. a proxy server and an IMAP client are two separate things, where is the connection? Why would you "copy the webInterface to the proxy"? What does that even mean? NextCloud has a web interface every user can use. No need to copy it. 2. Certainly you can apply whatever security measurements you want and that are supported by the user. But eep in mind that it is the NextCloud instance that takes care of authorization and actually owns all files uploaded into the instance.

Comment: When the user will login from Nextcloud Web Interface then only the user's data should be available on either NextCloud Server or proxy server not other user's data should be available on those server. In the case of IMAP client(e.g. Roundcube ) the data of particular user is copied on IMAP client. What IMAP client does similar feature I want on the Proxy Server or Nextcloud server

Comment: Sorry, but still unclear: Nextcloud grants access to the users data and data explicitly shared with that user, but not to data of any other users. So what data do you NOT want to be accessible? About the IMAP client: why don't you simply use an IMAP client independent from Nextcloud? And again: there already is a filter to present on the users data, no access to other users data is granted. I fail to understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: First of all thanks for your inputs. 1. If any how Nextcloud, installed at our end, got hacked, due to administrator negligence or application vulnerability, and hacker got server access  then the data which is available at Nextcloud will get affected. If the user's data is available on the server on demand basis(successfully logged in user's data) then only selective user's data will get affected. 2. As you have mentioned that the Nextcloud is having filters, So are these filters on application level or on OS level(e.g. Extended ACLs) ?

Comment: 3. And  I dont want to use IMAP client because it is for different purpose but in IMAP client e.g Roundcube same feature is implemented.

Comment: OK, I begin to understand where you are heading to... I am sceptical, though. I do not really see any realistic way to "copy the user's data" to some "proxy server" to limit access. Nextcloud is not about files inside a file system, that is only a small part of what it does. For that I would recommend to look for something else, some web based file systemfrontend. Nextcloud is about collaboration, sharing of data, it relies heavily on database entries which you cannot copy, you would have stale references and a broken system. Maybe take a look at an application filewall to harden the system.

Comment: OK I'll see some alternative solutions and thanks for your comments